# Компоненты Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, objective-c

Добрый день. Я не так давно начал писать приложения под мак, и сейчас стоит задача выводить информацию в окна.
Информация должны выводиться построчно, допустим из массива. Но при наведении на строку должна быть возможность получить событие и номер строки на которую неведена мышка. Я не могу понять какую компоненту для этого мне использовать, что бы и информацию выводить и события поддерживались.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NSTableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

**UPD.**

[Handling Mouse Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH6)

Для поиска текущей ячейки дергайте методы

```
NSTableView#rowAtPoint
```

и/или

```
NSTableView#columnAtPoint
```

Comment: а там точно можно получить событие наведения?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь.